# How to provide the link picture and link name when posting a post on the new Facebook v2.10

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the older version of Facebook API we can pass as parameters the `name`,  `picture` and `link` fields when posting a post on Facebook API.

But it seems that they deprecated these fields last July 2017. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/feed

I can't use the `object_attachment` parameter since you need to upload the image first, which means it will appear on user's Facebook photos.

Now, How can I do the same action on the new API with those fields being deprecated?

Comment: You can’t; unless you are the “owner” of the link in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

It's not a parameter, instead you need to add meta on the page you want to get "posted" to Facebook.